# How wmic enable horizontal scaling on command prompt window

Tags: windows, scaling, command-prompt

When open command prompt window. I found black fixed size windows that can scaling only vertical direction, but when i type **wmic** command it seem horizontal scaling also available. I just suspect what method that **wmic** force command prompt windows like that. Does one can explain?

Answer (score 1):

A console program can change the size of the screen buffer (You can also have more than one screen buffer, but only one can be visible)

See [SetConsoleScreenBufferSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686044%28VS.85%29.aspx)()